# Spring service init flow in Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, redis

I'm trying to write a simple Redis interface service in Spring/Kotlin and I'm having some trouble on understanding the way properties are supposed to initialize.

The `application.properties` file specifies the `redis.host` and `redis.port` values for Redis.  Then I wanted to setup a `RedisClient` and `StatefulRedisConnection` object to use internally with helper functions.

My issue is that although this compiles when I run I get:

```
@Service
class RedisService {

    @Value("\${redis.host}")
    private val host: String = "localhost"

    @Value("\${redis.port}")
    private val port: Int = 6379

    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    private lateinit var client: RedisClient
    private lateinit var connection: StatefulRedisConnection<String, String>

    @PostConstruct
    private fun setupConnection() {

        log.info("Creating connection to: [redis://$host:$port]")
        client = RedisClient.create(
                RedisURI.create("redis://$host:$port")
        )
        connection = client.connect()
    }
}
```

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property connection has not been initialized

What is the proper way to setup properties that need to be built "programmatically".  Do they need to be functions with the `@Bean` annotation or something like that?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is much better:

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    fun getRedisConnection(
        @Value("\${redis.host}") host: String,
        @Value("\${redis.port}") port: String) = RedisClient.create(RedisURI.create("redis://$host:$port")).connect()
}

@Service
class RedisService(private val connection: StatefulRedisConnection<String?,String?>) {
    private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    fun useConnection() {
        // use connection here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at

https://github.com/clivethescott/redis-kotlin-spring-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/redisdemo/controller/StudentController.kt

https://github.com/clivethescott/redis-kotlin-spring-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/redisdemo/config/RedisConfig.kt

**lateinit** fields have to be `@Autowired` and **connection** has to be via a `@Bean` annotation. Then `redisClient.connect()` as helper method would fine in your `@Service` class